# Stuck at [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I seem to be a bit stuck here trying to setup my new app.

I tried:

```
import angular from 'angular';
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

and I tried:

```
const angular = require('angular');
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

I still keep getting

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=app
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:322:1),
```

I already installed angular with npm and this is from my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
  },
```

Any ideas?

Comment: your module name is `myApp` and not `app` just check what have you used with the `ng-app` directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says

**`Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available!`**

Somewhere  in your application you are trying to use **`ng-app='app'`** , rename it to **`ng-app='myApp'`**

Comment: I havnt gotten so far yet. I tried to reinstall angular and now I get this: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular' -  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 ./app/main/app.js`

Comment: Could it be something in the webpack?  I dont know much about how that works.

Comment: try with npm install --save @angular

Comment: That did it with the install unfortunately im still getting the error.  I took a screenshot of my terminal and the error log.  https://db.tt/gom0eDAIIU  My app.js only have one line: `import angular from 'angular';`

Comment: do a search for '''app' in all the files you have

Comment: Yes you were right!!!  I did have an index.html with the line `<html ng-app="app" lang="en">` - I changed it to myApp and now it works :)  Thanks for helping me out :)